# Order entries based on date field in the Control Panel

Tags: entries, admin, ordering

I have some entries and I want to order them in the Control Panel based on a date field of those entries. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 4):

The [CpSortableCustomColumns](https://github.com/mmikkel/CpSortableCustomColumns-Craft) plugin lets you sort your element index tables on custom fields. Sounds like it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only Date/Time fields you can sort entries in Craft by are Post Date, Expiry Date, Date Created or Date Updated. You can't sort your entries in Craft by a *custom* Date/Time field.

Craft does allow you to define which fields you would like visible when viewing your sections in the control panel. To test this out, I created a new Date/Time field and tried to sort my entries by that field, but wasn't able.

**Edit**

I should also mention that Craft entries are sortable in the control panel by this dropdown field, but only by the Date/Time fields mentioned above:

[image]